# Send array data to laravel controller with Vue

Tags: arrays, laravel, vue.js, controller

I'm stuck at my coding. How do i send the array data to the Laravel controller? Usually i bind the data to a form using this.form.something="" then send them to the controller using axios, but how to do it with array? Should i use form or is there a way to send them without using form? Thanks.

**Vue Componenet**

```
<template>
    <form submit.prevent="submitData">
        <div class="jumbotron bg-dark col-md-10 offset-md-1">
                <div class="card card-body bg-dark" v-for="(user,index) in users" :key="index">
                        <h5>
                        <span class="badge badge-success mb-3 float-left">Data {{index+1}}</span>
                        <span style="cursor:pointer" class="float-right badge badge-danger mb-3" @click="deleteData(index)">X</span>
                        </h5>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                <label for="email" class="text-white">Username:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" v-model="user.username">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                <label for="pwd" class="text-white">Password:</label>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" v-model="user.password">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                <label for="pwd" class="text-white">Phone Number:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" v-model="user.phone">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                <label for="pwd" class="text-white">Email</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" v-model="user.email">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div> 
             <br>
                <button class="btn btn-secondary float-right"  @click="addMoreData()" title="Click to add row"><span class="fa fa-plus-square"></span> &nbsp;Add More Data</button>
        </div>

        <div class="jumbotron bg-dark col-md-10 offset-md-1 ">
            <button class="btn btn-success col-md-6 offset-md-3 p-3" type="submit"><span class="fa fa-plus-square"></span> &nbsp;Export to Microsoft Excel</button>
        </div> 
    </form>
```

**Script**

```
<script>
export default {
    data(){
      return{  
            users: [{
                username:'',
                password:'',
                phone:'',
                email:''
            }]
      }
    },
    methods:{
        addMoreData(){
            this.users.push({
                username: '', 
                password: '' , 
                email: '',
                phone:''
                });
        },
        deleteData(index){
            this.users.splice(index,1)  
        },
        submitData(){

      }
    },
    mounted() {
        console.log('Component mounted.')
    }
}
```

Comment: You can put your submit button inside the v-for loop and pass an index to submitData exactly the same way you are doing with deleteData. From this index you can retrieve the corresponding user in the array and submit.

Comment: I want to submit all the data at once. Like if the user adds 3 extra row data, then if they click the submit button, all that data will be sent @MuratK

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, just need to send the array to Laravel. Here's an example:

```
submitData(){
  // Here we send the data to '/users/store' route, 
  // using POST method and 'this.users' array as data
  axios.post('/users/store', this.users)
    .then(function (response) {
      // If the request is successful, we can do whatever we want with the response here
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      // If there's an error, treat it here
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Still using the above example, in the UserController you would receive the data like this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    /*  
        $request->all() contains all the data you sent
        in this case, the users array, but you should always
        validate it before, using FormRequest, for example: 
        https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#form-request-validation
    */
    User::create($request->all()); // Here we save all users to database

    // returning the data you sent before, just for testing.
    return response()->json([$request->all()]);
}
```

Comment: got this error message: "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'username' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `user` (`username`, `password`, `email`, `phone`) values (?, ?, ?, ?))"

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to respond... Could you please do: **dd($request->all())** in the first line of the store method and post the result here?